# Mutate new variable based on group-level statistic

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to append the group-maximum to table of observations, e.g:

```
iris %>% split(iris$Species) %>% 
    lapply(function(l) mutate(l, species_max = max(Sepal.Width))) %>% 
    bind_rows() %>% .[c(1,51,101),]
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species species_max
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa         4.4
51           7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor         3.4
101          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica         3.8
```

Is there a more elegant `dplyr::group_by` solution to achieve this?

Comment: You could purrr-ify it: `library(tidyverse); iris %>% split(.$Species) %>% map(mutate, species_max = max(Sepal.Width)) %>% map_df(slice, 1)` or maybe better, go the opposite route and nest: `iris %>% nest(-Species) %>% mutate(species_max = map_dbl(data, ~max(.x$Sepal.Width)), data = map(data, slice, 1)) %>% unnest()`. Or just keep it all in strict dplyr and go with docendo's answer.

Comment: @Axeman read the title - mean/max is hardly the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
group_by(iris, Species) %>% 
  mutate(species_max = max(Sepal.Width)) %>% 
  slice(1)

# Source: local data frame [3 x 6]
# Groups: Species [3]
# 
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species species_max
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>     <fctr>       <dbl>
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa         4.4
# 2          7.0         3.2          4.7         1.4 versicolor         3.4
# 3          6.3         3.3          6.0         2.5  virginica         3.8
```

The difficulty here is that you need to summarise multiple columns (for which `summarise_all` would be great) but at the same time you need to add a new column (for which you either need a simple `summarise` or `mutate` call).

---

In this regard `data.table` allows greater flexibility since it only relies on a list in its `j`-argument. So you can do it as follows with `data.table`, just as a comparison:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(iris)
dt[, c(lapply(.SD, first), species_max = max(Sepal.Width)), by = Species]
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I thought I'd tried this, but I guess I got something wrong.